# How to format logs in python?

Tags: python, logging, configuration

So I'm trying to make a keylogger (For educational purposes only) and I follow a [tutorial](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/python-keylogger/). The way how logging keystrokes implemented in tutorial does not fit to me. I'm trying to edit code from tutorial to log keystrokes without the `asctime` on the start, just the text that gets typed in.

I'm new in python so I have just tried to google some stuff but cant find any answer

This is line in source I need to modify:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
```

If i type `Abcd` I want it to write `Abcd`, and if I type `Hello world`, the output should be `Hello world`.

Currently it writes each letter from new line.
edit : Ok So i got the asctime thing out, but now i want to know how i can make it so that its pure output, and not each letter is in a line by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete `asctime` from logs you can just delete it from `format`:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")
```

To fix "each letter form new line" you can change terminator to empty string:

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.terminator = ""
```

***P.S.*** Keylogger isn't the best project to start learning programming language.

Comment: ok the asctime thing is solved now but i still cant solve the line thing. how to change terminator if i dont have it? how can i add it ?

Comment: @locipro you have it by default, just add provided code before calling `basicConfig()`.

Comment: prntscr.com/p03tsk Well this is the whole thing, it still makes it letter by letter . This is the output prntscr.com/p03u5s